# genrating sliding piece moves on bitboard efficiently without magic bitboard

Tags: python, performance, python-chess, bitboard

I'm currently working to improve a chess engine in python. more specifically I'm working on the move generation of sliding pieces, like rooks and bishops. originally I used this loop function for both rook and bishop moves:

```python
def get_rook_moves(self, color, position_bitboard):

    # Get the bitboard for the bishop's position
    self.update_occupied_sqaures()
    original_position_bitboard = position_bitboard

    moves = 0

    rank_8 = 0xff00000000000000
    rank_1 = 0x00000000000000ff
    file_a = 0x101010101010101
    file_h = 0x8080808080808080

    enemy_occupied_sqaures = self.occupied_black_sqaures if color == 'w' else self.occupied_white_sqaures
    friendly_occupied_sqaures = self.occupied_white_sqaures if color == 'w' else self.occupied_black_sqaures
    #diagonal 1 or north east
    while not position_bitboard & rank_8:
      position_bitboard <<= 8
      if position_bitboard & enemy_occupied_sqaures:
        moves |= position_bitboard
        break
      elif position_bitboard & friendly_occupied_sqaures:
        break
      moves |= position_bitboard
    

    position_bitboard = original_position_bitboard
    #diagonal 2 or south east
    while not position_bitboard & rank_1:
      position_bitboard >>= 8
      if position_bitboard & enemy_occupied_sqaures:
        moves |= position_bitboard
        break
      elif position_bitboard & friendly_occupied_sqaures:
        break
      moves |= position_bitboard

    position_bitboard = original_position_bitboard
    #diagonal 2 or south east
    while not position_bitboard & file_h:
      position_bitboard <<= 1
      if position_bitboard & enemy_occupied_sqaures:
        moves |= position_bitboard
        break
      elif position_bitboard & friendly_occupied_sqaures:
        break
      moves |= position_bitboard
    
    position_bitboard = original_position_bitboard
    #diagonal 2 or south east
    while not position_bitboard & file_a:
      position_bitboard >>= 1
      if position_bitboard & enemy_occupied_sqaures:
        moves |= position_bitboard
        break
      elif position_bitboard & friendly_occupied_sqaures:
        break
      moves |= position_bitboard

    # Return the final bitboard containing the bishop's legal moves
    return moves
```

but after looking at more efficient methods I settled on two, subtraction fill and kogge stone fill. Both functions used a singular fill algorithm combine with rotations to generate a fill for each direction.

subtration fill:

```python
def east_fill (position_bitboard, occupied_sqaures):  
    #consolodate piece position, occupied sqaures, and h file, 2 operations 
    occInclRook = position_bitboard | occupied_sqaures | h
    #xor h to piece position and xor consolodation of privious line, 4 operations
    occExclRook = (position_bitboard & ~h)  ^ occInclRook
    #subtract piece position from privous line, and xor cosolodation, 2 operations
    rookAttacks = (occExclRook - position_bitboard) ^ occInclRook
    #xor out friendly pieces from rookattacks, 2 operations
    return rookAttacks
```

kogge stone fill:

```python
def north_fill (position_bitboard, occupied_sqaures, enemy_occupied_sqaures):

    #Fill north direction of piece, 6 operations
    fillnorth = position_bitboard 
    fillnorth |= fillnorth << 8
    fillnorth |= fillnorth << 16
    fillnorth |= fillnorth << 32

    #genreate blockers based on first fill and determine cosest blocker, 2 operations
    blockers = fillnorth & occupied_sqaures
    closest_blocker = blockers & -blockers

    #back fill north direction starting from closest blocker, 6 operations
    backfillnorth = closest_blocker
    backfillnorth |= backfillnorth << 8
    backfillnorth |= backfillnorth << 16
    backfillnorth |= backfillnorth << 32
    #and out complimetary of backfill, 5 operations
    fillnorth &= ~(backfillnorth^(closest_blocker & enemy_occupied_sqaures))

    return fillnorth
```

when using these with a combination of three rotations for each direction in the subtraction fill, and four rotations for each direction in the kogge stone fill. while the induvial algorithms were faster than the loop fill in one direction, when doing all directions, the kogge and subtraction fill were both 13 nanoseconds slower using correct rotations, and 3 nanoseconds slower using the fastest rotations

how a rotated direction would look:

```python
fos = r.flipVertical(occupied_sqaures)
fes = r.flipVertical(enemy_occupied_sqaures)
fpb = r.flipVertical(position_bitboard)

fillsouth = r.flipVertical(north_fill (fos, fes, fpb))
```

i got these results using the fastest rotation and reducing the number of rotations from 4 to 3 on subtraction fill:

subtraction_fill average time (microseconds): 1.4904390062854784
kogge_fill average time (microseconds): 2.3933798188355007
loop average time (microseconds): 2.7865687436801885

subtraction fill all directions average time (microseconds): 3.5131265412457604
kogge fill all directions average time (microseconds): 6.532563156101725
loop all directions average time (microseconds): 2.8232414561724983

90 degree clockwise rotation average time (microseconds, calling other rotations): 1.3400337985097461
90 degree counter clockwise rotation (microseconds, calling other rotations): 1.3546858758556926
mirror rotation average time (microseconds): 0.711181154469959
vertical flip rotation average time (microseconds): 0.6649066519999233
diagnal flip A8H1 rotation average time (microseconds): 0.9260225979791413
diagnal flip A1H8 time (microseconds): 0.8079409734359478

and when removing all rotatiions from both kogge and subtraction fill i get this:

subtraction fill all directions average time (microseconds): 1.6138958483908323
kogge fill all directions average time (microseconds): 2.5905292420269417
loop all directions average time (microseconds): 2.569006541722452

I'm just usure if I implemented the rotations in an efficient way, or whether it would be better to d ono rotations at all. also sorry if the question is confusing, its my first time doing one of these and the topic itself is kind of confusing.

Comment: it is a great bit of code, but the question is too long... please reduce to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: For chess programming, it is better to ask on this forum : http://talkchess.com/forum3/index.php